# How do I enable bookmark syncing in Chrome on OS X without launching from Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, google-bookmarks

I recently switched to a Mac and started using Chrome since it was my preferred browser in Windows.  It doesn't look like the Chrome OS X Dev Channel doesn't have bookmark syncing or extensions yet.

From Chromium documentation - it looks like this is available it just has to been enabled via a command line switch.  I don't want to have to launch Chrome from Terminal every time?  Can I modify the application somehow to always launch with those flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chrome dev channel now includes extensions and bookmark syncing.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest version of [Chromium](http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/snapshots/chromium-rel-mac/) (the open source variant of Chrome) which has extensions enabled.

Comment: What about Google Bookmark sync?

Comment: Not sure what Bookmarks you're looking to sync but there are a bunch of Bookmark extensions available: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/search/2?q=bookmarks 

Browsing through that list I see at least 5 extensions that deal with "google bookmarks" specifically.

Comment: I'm talking specifically about bookmark syncing that's built in to Chrome for Windows.  http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139

Comment: Just look under preferences: http://img.skitch.com/20100105-kue533t68cbk8hbea9cwy312c5.png

Comment: This might have been available in Chromium but it was not in Chrome.  Anyway - the new Chrome dev version has extensions and bookmark syncing so, it's a moot point.